# Django and WSGI: Error 500 again

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

Well, i get this 500 error again and again. Everything seemed to work for a few days but when i've tried to load website in browser now, it returned me 500. Apache logs aren't descriptive, all i can see there is:

```
Sun May 26 20:39:34 2013] [error] [client 188.134.73.102] mod_wsgi (pid=5087): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/empirik/data/www/mywebsite.com.ru/myproject/wsgi.py'.
[Sun May 26 20:39:34 2013] [error] [client 188.134.73.102] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun May 26 20:39:34 2013] [error] [client 188.134.73.102]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
[Sun May 26 20:39:34 2013] [error] [client 188.134.73.102]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Sun May 26 20:39:34 2013] [error] [client 188.134.73.102]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in get_response
[Sun May 26 20:39:34 2013] [error] [client 188.134.73.102]     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
[Sun May 26 20:39:34 2013] [error] [client 188.134.73.102]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 228, in handle_uncaught_exception
[Sun May 26 20:39:34 2013] [error] [client 188.134.73.102]     return callback(request, **param_dict)
[Sun May 26 20:39:34 2013] [error] [client 188.134.73.102]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 91, in _wrapped_view
[Sun May 26 20:39:34 2013] [error] [client 188.134.73.102]     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
[Sun May 26 20:39:34 2013] [error] [client 188.134.73.102]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/defaults.py", line 32, in server_error
[Sun May 26 20:39:34 2013] [error] [client 188.134.73.102]     t = loader.get_template(template_name) # You need to create a 500.html template.
[Sun May 26 20:39:34 2013] [error] [client 188.134.73.102]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 145, in get_template
[Sun May 26 20:39:34 2013] [error] [client 188.134.73.102]     template, origin = find_template(template_name)
[Sun May 26 20:39:34 2013] [error] [client 188.134.73.102]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 138, in find_template
[Sun May 26 20:39:34 2013] [error] [client 188.134.73.102]     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)
[Sun May 26 20:39:34 2013] [error] [client 188.134.73.102] TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html
```

Is there any way to get more specific information then this TemplateDoesNotExist exception?

Comment: One way is to temporary set `DEBUG=True` and see the standard django error page with a lot of useful information. Also, consider defining 500.html like suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639769/how-can-i-find-out-what-500-error-am-i-getting-in-django). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks to alecxe, i figured out the reason of my problem. It's just ALLOWED_HOSTS feature that is required when `DEBUG = False`.